# Excel Fazer lista e ir buscar valores

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com uma pequena duvida ao fazer um ficheiro em excel.

No meu excel tenho uma página (Folha1) com tabelas e varios valores. 
Gostava de saber se é possivel eu fazer uma lista na "folha2" e ao escolher uma opção ele dar-me um valor que se encontra na Tabela da "folha1" para poder fazer um calculo na folha dois.

Folha 1:

```
1 - 100 - 200
2 - 200 - 300
```

Folha 2:

```
// aqui tenho uma lista com o Valor 1 e 2 e quero que ao selecionar o 2 mostre o valor 200 e 300
2 - 200 - 300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria criar uma lista de depois uma função [PROCV](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/excel-help/procv-HP005209335.aspx) para buscar os valores, das outras colunas, exemplo:

Crie uma planilha chamada **lista** que conterá os dados a serem buscados, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Excel dados]

Crie outra planilha chamada **buscar**,  selecione o conjunto de células onde deseja criar a lista, vá na guia  [image: guia dados]  depois em   [image: valida dados guia] em **permitir** seleciona a opção **lista**, e em **fonte** selecione o intervalo de células da lista, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: validação de dados]

Será criado a lista com os valores da primeira coluna da planilha lista.

Na célula B1 da planilha buscar faça uma função [PROCV](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/excel-help/procv-HP005209335.aspx), para procurar na lista o valor selecionado e retornar a coluna com índice 2:

```
=PROCV(A1;lista!$A$1:$C$2;2)
```

Esta função, irá procurar na planilha **lista** o valor selecionado na célula A1 e retornar a coluna com índice 2, ou seja selecionou 1 retornará 100, selecionou 2 retornará 200.

Repita o procedimento para a célula C1 para retornar a coluna com índice 3

```
=PROCV(A1;lista!$A$1:$C$2;3)
```

**Resultado**
[image: resultado lista e buscar]